# bootstrap 2014 theme running slow on godaddy linux hosting

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I am unable to fix the speed of bootstrap website used in www.bengalwools.co.in ...

please help me fix the CDN for the javascript and css or anything else to speed up my website...

the code for the index.html is :
[all links available in inspect element](http://www.bengalwool.co.in)

Comment: instead of cdn links . why don't you download and keep it in your server .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [GTMetrix](http://www.gtmetrix.com/) & refer their suggestions to improve speed.